# Spark: Unsupported class version error

Tags: java, java-7, apache-spark

I am trying to run a java spark job, using spark-submit, on a cluster where all nodes have java 1.7 installed.

The job fails with a java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/windlogics/dmf/wether/MyClass: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0.

This error seems to be caused by compiling with an lower version of java and running with a higher version. However, I have verified that the code is being compiled with 1.7.

Also, the job works fine when the master is set to local. How can I go about debugging and fixing this error?

A part of the error log is below.

> 15/01/21 15:14:57 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, sphddp07.zzz.local): java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/zzz/dmf/wether/MyClass: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
>           java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>           java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
>           java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
>           java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>           java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
>           java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
>           java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
>           java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>           java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>           java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>           java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
>           org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:59)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1574)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1461)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1311)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
>           scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
>           sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
>           scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
>           sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
>           java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
>           org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:62)
>           org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:87)
>           org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:57)
>           org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
>           org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:177)
>           java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>           java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)

Comment: "all nodes have java 1.7 installed" - but are you *running* with Java 1.7? Can you log the value of the `java.version` system property?

Comment: On the node that it fails on this is the java version                                         -bash-3.2$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

Comment: Well that's what happens when you run `java` from the command line from bash - but is that definitely the version that's running and failing? That's why I suggested you should add some logging.

Comment: I added System.err.println("Java Version: " + System.getProperty("java.version")) in my main method, which produced "Java Version: 1.7.0_45". Although, I don't actually know if this piece of code is being run on the cluster node.

Comment: Right, so you need to find that out. Sorry to be so picky, but when it looks like an environmental problem, you really need to find out the exact version running *where the problem is*. (Version 51 *is* for Java 1.7, so it looks like something is running an earlier version somewhere.)

Comment: Thanks. I will keep poking around and post if I find something.

Comment: Hello, was this problem resolved? Perhaps the application is using Java 8?

Comment: @inno what type of cluster do you use? Spark cluster or Yarn? depending on which, I might have the answer

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error message. I discovered that when I typed 'java -version' it was 1.7. I needed Java 8. Here's how to update:

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0
sudo alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue tried setting appropriate JAVA_HOME in bashrc files on both master and slave machines, but this did not help.

Then when I set JAVA_HOME at whole cluster level,  major.minor error is gone. I use cloudera, so I had to set JAVA_HOME in cloudera manager to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the Spark version and corresponding JDK requirements from Spark Documentation page https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/.

For example, Spark 2.4.5 runs on Java 8 and I had Java 13 on my system. Resolved the issue by moving my system to the required JDK.

Comment: you can have multi version of Java and still run the code, only thing you need is to set the proper Java Home and you are good to go.